# Zip folder created by shell script not opening

Tags: shell, unix, zip

I am using the below script to zip the folder and it contents :-

```
cd /home/fs/Inbnd/
pwd

tar -cvf Image_test_new.zip Image

chmod 777 *
chown fusionc:staff *
```

The file image.zip is getting created successfully. But the file is not opening and showing an error :

[image: Error]
Is there an error in the ststement I am using to zip?

Comment: How do you `cd` to a Linux filesystem path in Windows?

Comment: @Inian. I am using tectia client. It doesnot identify zip command and i want .zip extension for which i am using this command. it is generating files in .zip extension but is not extracting

Comment: @Inian it will create .gz extension files which i do not need

Comment: Am I missing something?  Or does tar -cvf only create a tar archive, and not a zip.  So he's making a tar-ball and simply calling it a *.zip, when it isn't a zip-format file at all.  Its just a blob of concatenated data of the Image file/path under /home/fs/Inbnd.  What what you want is a zip, then create a zip with the appropriate tool/syntax.

Comment: @TheHairyOne- i cannot use zip -r syntax as its not readble by Tectia. Do you know of any other syntax ? Pls share

Answer (score 1):

tar -cvf makes a tar ball, not a zip archive.  You can verify this in Linux, before trying to open it in Windows.

```
touch not_going_to_be_a_zip
tar -cvf not_really_a.zip not_going_to_be_a_zip
unzip not_really_a.zip
Archive:  not_really_a.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of not_really_a.zip or
        not_really_a.zip.zip, and cannot find not_really_a.zip.ZIP, period.
```

The zip utility does a good job at making zip archives.

```
touch will_be_a_zip
zip i_am_a.zip will_be_a_zip      Archive:  i_am_a.zip
    testing: will_be_a_zip            OK
No errors detected in compressed data of i_am_a.zip.
unzip -t i_am_a.zip
  Archive:  i_am_a.zip
    testing: will_be_a_zip            OK
No errors detected in compressed data of i_am_a.zip.
```

Note:  unzip -t will test the archive only, make sure its okay before trying it in Windows.

Comment: i cannot test zip statement as i am using tectia client which will not recognise the zip statement. is there a way to create tar with gz exension and then rename it to zip or something?

Comment: _"is there a way to create tar with gz exension and then rename it to zip or something"_  You are missing the point.   However you name it, a `tar.gz` file is _not_ a `zip` file.

Comment: If your system lacks a zip utility, then you can use "tar zcvf Image_test_new.zip Image"; this however will create a real gunzip compression file and when you download it to Windows you'll need a gunzip capable tool, like WinRAR/7Zip/etc. to open/view/extract.  If your system is connected to the internet, you can try adding a zip utility.  Search

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use the standard approach like **zip/unzip** and if you have **JDK** installed on your machine then you can use the **jar** utility from JDK's bin folder.

*To zip a file*

```
jar cvf zip_file_name.zip image.jpg
```

The only overhead is that it will add a META-INF folder with a file named MANIFEST.MF in it, which you can delete after extracting the zip file.

Comment: I have to load the zip file automatically into a folder. I cannot have an extra file .MF in the zip flder

Answer (score -1):

Try to use zip command instead of tar command.

Comment: @Arun- I am using Tectia client. It does not support zip command

Comment: @divya.trehan573 - If that's case, try to use WinRar or 7z for unzipping. WinZip will fail to open